# Libgdx when screen changed, socket events still running in previous screen

Tags: java, node.js, socket.io, libgdx

I'm making online game in libgdx.I'm using socket.io for server and I'm using rooms.But I have a problem with screen changes.I have two screen class, I'm connecting to server only once from town class (Player starting in town). and when player went to weaponshop I'm emitting getPlayers method to player. but getPlayers method calling in town and weaponshop. I don't want call getPlayers method in town class when player in weaponshop class.

My socket variable defined in Multiplayer class for access everywhere:

```
public class Multiplayer extends Game {
    public static Socket socket;

    ...

    @Override
    public void create () {
        game = this;

        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:8080");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render();
    }
}
```

Town Class:

```
public Town() {
    ...
    connectToRoom();
    configSocketEvents();
}

private void connectToRoom() {
        try {
            if (!socket.connected())
                socket.connect();

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            try {
                data.put("newroom", "town");
                socket.emit("joinRoom", data);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Gdx.app.log("SOCKET.IO", "Error sending update data!");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    private void configSocketEvents() {
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "Connected");
                }
            }).on("getPlayers", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                        System.out.println("gs getPlayers");
                        JSONArray objects = (JSONArray) args[0];
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
                                FriendlyPlayer coopPlayer = new FriendlyPlayer(playerTex, world, game, 1220, 1100, 24, 32);
                                Vector2 position = new Vector2();
                                Float vx, vy;
                                Float bx, by;
                                position.x = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("x")).floatValue();
                                position.y = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("y")).floatValue();
                                vx = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vx")).floatValue();
                                vy = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vy")).floatValue();
                                bx = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("bx")).floatValue();
                                by = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("by")).floatValue();
                                String username = objects.getJSONObject(i).getString("username");
                                Integer level = objects.getJSONObject(i).getInt("level");
                                coopPlayer.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
                                coopPlayer.vx = vx;
                                coopPlayer.vy = vy;
                                coopPlayer.bx = bx;
                                coopPlayer.by = by;
                                coopPlayer.username = username;
                                coopPlayer.level = level;
                                friendlyPlayers.put(objects.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"), coopPlayer);
                                coopPlayer.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        }
                }
            });
    }
```

WeaponShop Class:

```
public WeaponShop() {
    ...
    connectToRoom();
    configSocketEvents();
}

private void connectToRoom() {
        try {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            try {
                data.put("newroom", "weaponshop");
                socket.emit("joinRoom", data);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Gdx.app.log("SOCKET.IO", "Error sending update data!");
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    private void configSocketEvents() {
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "Connected");
                }
            }).on("getPlayers", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                        System.out.println("ws getPlayers");
                        JSONArray objects = (JSONArray) args[0];
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
                                FriendlyPlayer coopPlayer = new FriendlyPlayer(playerTex, world, game, 56, 195, 24, 32);
                                Vector2 position = new Vector2();
                                Float vx, vy;
                                Float bx, by;
                                String username;
                                position.x = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("x")).floatValue();
                                position.y = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("y")).floatValue();
                                vx = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vx")).floatValue();
                                vy = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vy")).floatValue();
                                bx = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("bx")).floatValue();
                                by = ((Double) objects.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("by")).floatValue();
                                username = objects.getJSONObject(i).getString("username");
                                coopPlayer.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
                                coopPlayer.vx = vx;
                                coopPlayer.vy = vy;
                                coopPlayer.bx = bx;
                                coopPlayer.by = by;
                                coopPlayer.username = username;
                                friendlyPlayers.put(objects.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"), coopPlayer);
                                coopPlayer.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                        }
                }
            });
    }
```

And my joinRoom method in server:

```
socket.on('joinRoom', function(data) {
        oldRoom = socket.room;
        socket.room = data.newroom;
        socket.leave(oldRoom);
        socket.join(socket.room);
        socket.emit("createPlayer");
        socket.to(oldRoom).emit('playerDisconnected', { id: socket.id });//socket.broadcast.to(oldRoom).emit('playerDisconnected', { id: socket.id });
        socket.to(socket.room).emit('newPlayer', { id: socket.id });//socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('newPlayer', { id: socket.id });

        if(oldRoom == 'town') {
            for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                if(players[i].id == socket.id) {
                    players.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        if(oldRoom == 'weaponshop') {
            for(var i = 0; i < weaponshopPlayers.length; i++) {
                if(weaponshopPlayers[i].id == socket.id) {
                    weaponshopPlayers.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        if(oldRoom == 'potionshop') {
            for(var i = 0; i < potionshopPlayers.length; i++) {
                if(potionshopPlayers[i].id == socket.id) {
                    potionshopPlayers.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        if(socket.room == 'town') {
            socket.emit('getPlayers', players);
            socket.emit('getMonsters', monsters);
            players.push(new player(socket.id, "", 0, "town", 1220 / 100, 1100 / 100, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        if(socket.room == 'weaponshop') {
            socket.emit('getPlayers', weaponshopPlayers);
            weaponshopPlayers.push(new player(socket.id, "", 0, "weaponshop", 56 / 100, 195 / 100, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        if(socket.room == 'potionshop') {
            socket.emit('getPlayers', potionshopPlayers);
            potionshopPlayers.push(new player(socket.id, "", 0, "potionshop", 56 / 100, 195 / 100, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        }

        console.log("Player (" + socket.id + ") switched room");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem is that you have no way to control when messages arrive on the socket regardless of what you do.

The player might have just changed from one room to another, but the message from the server might have been already on its way.

One thing you can do is to have a single connection to the server and send all requests via it. If a message arrives, you need to check whether its still valid for the current state (that you maintain on client side as well). If yes, forward it to the correct implementation, if not discard it.

This relies on you having a proper seperation between the different aspects of your game. So basically its a code design problem.

Using messages with the same format for different things is probably also not a good way. If you can not distinguish what the context of the message is, you are bound to end up communicating things that are unintentional.

Comment: Actually my problem, when the player in weaponshop class, configSocketMethods in town class still running.I must stop running configSocketMethods in town class.How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with 100% accuracy. You can try to deregister your callback using `off`, but that  probably won't help you if the callback is already running in the background.